# Understanding console.log(console.log(object))

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and js and I am trying to learn crux of javascript.

```
var obj1 = {
    name: 'rawn',
    fn: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
console.log(obj1.fn());
```

When I output this I get the object(as expected) - `{name: "rawn", fn: ƒ}` and on another line I get - `undefined`. So my question is why and how do I get `undefined`?

My understanding is that, we are writing this line - `console.log(obj1.fn());` as ,  `console.log(console.log(this))`, so how does javascript engine gives the result as `undefined` (what was put as undefined in the execution context)?

Comment: What *would* you expect as result here…?

Comment: @deceze i though it will simply print the object 2 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log(obj1.fn())` and `console.log(console.log(this))` are not equivalent at all, but they actually have the same result for the same reason: the inner function *does not `return` anything*. The return value of these functions is `undefined`. Which is what the outer `console.log` logs.

Comment: `console.log(obj1.fn()) and console.log(console.log(this)) are not equivalent at all`, but I thought when I say () in the fn(), it executes the my written code part i.e console.log(this)

Comment: oh yeah, i din't mean it literally,  I meant `console.log(this)` is called first from the `obj.fn()` and then the outer `console.log` is called

Comment: `If the function is passed to the function console.log(), then the function will display the value of the passed function().` Now I know whats going on !

Answer (score 1):

This is because of two reasons.  First, in `console.log(this);` the context of `this` inside the `fn` function is the object itself.  Hence it prints the guts of `obj1`.

Secondly, in `console.log(obj1.fn());`, you are actually calling the method which returns nothing. Instead if you say `console.log(obj1.fn);` it will return:

> ƒ () {
>                 console.log(this);
>               }

Hope this helps.